# What is the function of "(ClassName *)"

Tags: objective-c, class, syntax, casting

I have seen code statements that use '(ClassName *)' to reference certain objects, like in `UITableViewCell *myCell = (UITableViewCell*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];`.

I have no idea what this means or how it works and I would like to increase my understanding of this concept.

I have also seen that the same code is also used in method declaration and would like to understand if this uses the same concept and if not, how is it different, e.g.

`-(IBAction)myAction:(id)sender;`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That serves as a typecast. It converts the type of the pointer to the type within the parentheses. In this case, it is converting a `UIView` instance (the result of `` `viewWithTag: ``) to an instance of `UITableViewCell`.

In ObjC, an object to object typecast does not result in a type conversion. That is to say - there is no new instance created. Additionally, typecasting an object performs no dynamic type checking when performing a dynamic downcast (unlike `dynamic_cast` in C++ or typecasting in Java, where an exception may be thrown).

Because `-viewWithTag:` returns a `UIView` (or `NSView` on OS X), a typecast is used to tell the compiler "It's OK - I know this type returned is a `UITableViewCell` instance". Using the typecast allows you to downcast from `UIView` to its subclass `UITableViewCell` in the assignment expression to the variable, which allows you to use the object as a `UITableViewCell` with the compiler matching the message or variable with the type. Without the typecast, you would logically be using it as or assigning it to a `UIView` (or one of its superclasses), and the compiler would complain if you tried to use methods implemented by subclasses of the instance. For example - you could not successfully use the variable to access the UITableViewCell.accessoryView property without either a typecast, type erasure, or a compiler warning or error. The typecast is the least evil in this case.

Now in the case of `- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender;`, `id` is an untyped ObjC object. It has a special distinction in that it requires no typecast. For example:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(id)sender
{
  NSString * currentTitle = nil;
  currentTitle = sender.currentTitle; // << May be ambiguous to the compiler because `id` is not fully typed

  UIButton * button = sender; // << OK assign id to variable of arbitrary ObjC object type
  currentTitle = button.currentTitle; // << OK

  UIButton * castButton = (UIButton*)sender; // << although unnecessary, some people use this form.
  currentTitle = castButton.currentTitle; // << OK
   ...

   NSObject * object = button; // << OK. upcast from button to object. compiler knows it is an NSObject without typecasting.
```

Personally, I just wrap it all into the parameter -- which is fine for ObjC objects in method declarations as long as you know the type of the parameter which is being passed:

```
- (IBAction)myAction:(UIButton *)pButton
{
  NSString * currentTitle = pButton.currentTitle; // << OK
   ...
```

Comment: "it is converting a UIView instance to an instance of UITableViewCell" It is converting pointers. There is just one instance -- a UITableViewCell instance, and it doesn't change. "an object to object typecast" You cannot have an "object to object typecast"; only a pointer to pointer typecast. "Because -viewWithTag: returns a UIView" No, it returns `UIView *`. "Using the typecast allows you to downcast from UIView to its subclass UITableViewCell" You are downcasting from `UIView *` to `UITableViewCell *`.

Answer (score 0):

Is just a typecast necessary to suppress the compiler warning. 
In other words its saying to the compiler [self.view viewWithTag:1] is an UITableViewCell. Without that cast the compiler would complain that UIView is not a UITableViewCell.